# In Python Click how do I see --help for Subcommands whose parents have required options?

Tags: python, python-click

I have a similar problem to the one described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437472/in-python-click-how-do-i-see-help-for-subcommands-whose-parents-have-required), however I have required options before the command and not an argument. I have tried adapting the accepted answer to my situation but can not get it to work, for instance

```
#! python3

import click

    class PerCommandOptWantSubCmdHelp(click.Option):

    def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
        # check to see if there is a --help on the command line
        if any(arg in ctx.help_option_names for arg in args):

            # if asking for help see if we are a subcommand name
            for arg in opts.values():
                if arg in ctx.command.commands:

                    # this matches a sub command name, and --help is
                    # present, let's assume the user wants help for the
                    # subcommand
                    args = [arg] + args

        return super(PerCommandOptWantSubCmdHelp, self).handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)



@click.group()
def foo():
    pass

@click.group('map')
@click.option('-f', '--force', is_flag=True)
@click.option('-i', '--id')
@click.option('-b', '--base', required=True, cls=PerCommandOptWantSubCmdHelp)
def archive_map(force, id, base):
    click.echo('Map called')

volla.add_command(archive_map)


@click.command('bar')
@click.option('-t', '--template', required=True)
@click.option('-p', '--project', required=True)
def bar_command():
    pass

archive_map.add_command(bar_command);


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

But I still get this behavior

```
$ ./foo map bar --help
Usage: foo map [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'foo map --help' for help.

Error: Missing option '-b' / '--base'.
$
```

Any ideas for what I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this:

```py
class PerCommandOptWantSubCmdHelp(click.Option):

    def handle_parse_result(self, ctx, opts, args):
        # check to see if there is a --help on the command line
        if any(arg in ctx.help_option_names for arg in args):
            # if asking for help see if we are a subcommand name
            remaining_args = [arg for arg in args if arg not in ctx.help_option_names]
            for arg in remaining_args:

                if arg in ctx.command.commands:
                    click.echo(ctx.command.get_help(ctx))
                    click.echo()
                    click.echo(f'Command {arg} usage')
                    click.echo(ctx.command.commands[arg].get_help(ctx))

        return super(PerCommandOptWantSubCmdHelp, self).handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
```

Essentially, if you've invoked the subcommand with help, get the parent's help message, output it, and then output your current subcommand's help message.

Your output will look like this:

```
Usage: main.py map [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  -f, --force
  -i, --id TEXT
  -b, --base TEXT  [required]
  --help           Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  bar

Command bar usage:
Usage: main.py map [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -t, --template TEXT  [required]
  -p, --project TEXT   [required]
  --help               Show this message and exit.
Usage: main.py map [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'main.py map --help' for help.

Error: Missing option '-b' / '--base'.
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, it works! Is it possible to get rid of the error message when --help is given on the command line?

Comment: Hi Ermingol. Couldn't quite figure out how to get rid of the error message easily. What I could suggest is trying to make `base` not be required, and handle input validation inside your own method by hand. If an option is required, you might want to look into turning it into an argument, really. Let me know if that doesn't make sense

Comment: I'll have to think a bit about this. Perhaps making base into an argument is better (it is a required value that can't be assigned any default).